# File doesn't upload using react and axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a problem in uploading file so this is my request
[image]

and my code:

```
requestHandler = () => {
    try {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append( 
            "myFile", 
            this.state.file
          ); 
           
        let params = {
            settings:this.state.setting_url,
            name:this.state.imageName,
            diskFormat:this.state.diskFormat,
            containerFormat:this.state.containerFormat,
            file:formData
        }
        let resImage =  post(`openstacktenant-images/`,params)
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

jsx

```
<Form.Control type="file"                                     
         onChange={e => {
          this.setState({
             file: e.target.files[0]
          })
         }}
  />


 <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.requestHandler()}>
     submit
  </Button>
```

and error response
"The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."

```
 let resImage =  post(`openstacktenant-images/`,params)
```

this line works correctly and post is an axios request that i wrote it in another file

why file field in request doesn't contain uploaded file what is wrong with my code?

Comment: why are you appending the file to ```FormData```? Try to send it directly.

Comment: I tried it,still doesn't work

Comment: try ```console.log(err.response)``` and post the detail of the error in your question

Comment: @mostafa Could you share your `post` method?